# dell inspirion 7559 -- ubuntu 16.04 booted up using `nomodese` to login screen successfully but desktop is now showing after logging in

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, 16.04, dell

I'm a very novice user of ubuntu, tried installing ubuntu on my dell 7559 15" laptop. Installed it successfully after some search, I had to press `e` and add the following line to grub bootloader `nomodeset` added that... installed it successfully after when I went to start the ubuntu

I repeated the added `nomodest` in bootloader again to run ubuntu 16.04 ran it to login screen image below.

[image: Login screen showing sucessfully]

once I logged in no desktop loaded, the following image

[image: blank screen instead of desktop]

Any Idea?

Kindly help me, what should I do to get it working...

Comment: thank you @AndroidDev I'll try that today come back if i need any help regards

Comment: @AndroidDev I can't manage to do anything on that desktop... everything is blinking very very fast even terminal.... I'm using UEFI bios... as I said I'm not that technical when it comes to using ubuntu... please help

Comment: Blinking? What do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: blinking `display/display of` of the terminal at very rapid speed... like you blink your eye open close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try replacing `nomodeset` with `nouveau.modeset=0`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/586393)

Comment: This is very much a possible solution.  I can't test it cuz I don't have this particular hardware but I can assure you this problem is because of the i7 skylake processor & nvidia 960m GPU which this Laptop has.  I too had resolved the same issue on the same combination of processor & GPU using this command line argument

Comment: one more thing buddy, do I have to add this everytime when i boot my laptop to ubuntu OS ? is there a permanent fix?

Comment: You can make it permanent by editing the /etc/grub/default.cfg file.  Then run `sudo update-grub` .  Not sure about the exact commands, a quick Google search to update kernel parameters will tell you both